# Jira - Avoid getting mail on change on specific column on closed task I was watching

Tags: jira, project-management, agile-project-management

When working on tasks I'm a watching, mainly after there closed , there are several custom fields that aren't related to programming, but for version/project as link, image, tag ...

Currently I'm getting mail on every change on such columns

Can I setup to ignore changes in specific columns, maybe with specific statuses (as closed)?

A workaround will be to remove watching task that are closed, but it's problematic because task may be reopen

Comment: I just took a look at the JIRA notification schemes and it doesn't look like they allow you to differentiate between fields. It's pretty course grained really, the "Issue Updated" event triggers a notification. There also doesn't appear to be any way to link notifications to the status of an issue.

Comment: @BarnabyGolden is it a good idea/practice to remove myself from watching old closed tasks  ?

Comment: Closed tasks rarely get modified, so this is not usually a concern. My answer to your question would depend on how frequently you are receiving notifications. If your closed tasks get regularly updated then I would be tempted to stop watching them unless I needed to know about the changes.